# python list - can't convert to json

Tags: python, json

**Problem**

I'm trying to convert the results of a REDIS db query to json data. 
REDIS returns a SET of byte strings, which i convert to a LIST of regular strings.

I now need a way to convert to json to pass back to the caller of my REST interface.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
 TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable
```

**CODE**

This is the function that queries the database and where I attempt to convert from SET to LIST:

```
def get_db_email(mailbox):
    if DEBUG:  logging.info("get_db_email() debug started:")
    try:
        r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
        response = r.smembers(str(mailbox) + "-emails")  # returns a python "set"        
        if len(response) > 0:                
            jdata = []  # create a list
            for n in response:                
                if DEBUG: logging.info(n)
                #convert byte string to string
                jdata.append({n.decode("utf-8")})  # to get rid of "b" prefix 
            logging.info("****")
            logging.info(jdata)
            logging.info("####")
            return True, jdata
        else:
            return False, 500
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error("get_db_email() failed")
        logging.error(ex)
        return False, 500
```

Here's the function that calls the db query ...

```
@application.route("/widgets/api/<int:mailbox>/email", methods=['GET'])
def get_email(mailbox):
    if DEBUG: 
        logging.info("get_email() debug started:")
    status, data_list = get_db_email(mailbox)
    if DEBUG: 
        logging.info(status)
        logging.info(type(data_list))
    if status == True:
        logging.info("poof")
        json_data = json.dumps(data_list)
        logging.info('the magic dragon')
        return json_data
    else:
        return abort(data)
```

Here's the output in the logs that I see:

```
root - INFO - b'test@yahoo.com'
root - INFO - ****
root - INFO - [{'test@yahoo.com'}]
root - INFO - ####
root - INFO - True
root - INFO - <class 'list'>
root - INFO - poof
```

based on the logs, i'm hoping you can see that get_db_email returns a real list object (contents wrapped btn the "=====" and "#####" is outputted by that method.)
And then to confirm that it's a list, the calling function makes a call to type(data_list) and the logs show that it's of type

The system bombs when it tries to make the call to json.dumps()
From what I've read and other code samples, I thought I could pass a list object into json.dumps.
If you can show me where I've gone wrong, I'd appreciate it. 
Thanks.

Comment: The error message in your question says "Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable", which implies that you haven't converted the data to a list. Can you show the code where that conversion is done?

Comment: `[{'test@yahoo.com'}]`: that's a `list` containing a `set` that contains a single element.

Comment: Right... forgot that the output is actually printed here. Sorry about that.

Comment: @FynnBecker I see.  I'm such a noob.  Can you tell me how to fix? I updated the post to include the get_db_email() logic

Comment: `jdata.append({n.decode("utf-8")})` appends a `set` containing a `str` to `jdata`. If you don't want to append a `set` but just the contained `str`, don't wrap it into a `set` literal.

Comment: DOH!  I missed that!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
        jdata = []  # create a list
        for n in response:                
            #convert byte string to string
            jdata.append({n.decode("utf-8")})  # to get rid of "b" prefix
```

You are creating a list of sets. This should be:

```
        jdata = []  # create a list
        for n in response:                
            #convert byte string to string
            jdata.append(n.decode("utf-8"))
```

or more simply:

```
       jdata = [n.decode("utf-8") for n in response]
```

also, the purpose of `bytes.decode(encoding)` is not "to get rid of 'b' prefix" but [to build a unicode string from the byte string](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)